# Edid for 5k monitors

Tags: drivers, display, edid

The `horizontal Addressable Video in pixels` and `Vertical Addressable Video in lines` fields in the EDID 1.4/1.3 structures are limited to a value in the range of 0-4095. For 5k monitors and higher resolutions how can this limitation be exceeded?

I haven't been able to find any information in the specs or other documents. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you have to look at [DisplayID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DisplayID)?

Answer (score 1):

The EDID standard was updated to support Short Video Descriptors in the CEA Extension Block. SVDs include an index into a table of resolutions. You can read more about it here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Display_Identification_Data